# Allow update on a table only through jdbc in sql server , oracle and postgres

Tags: java, sql, oracle, postgresql, jdbc

How to ensure that update on a table is allowed only through jdbc by the same user and not allowed through any client. Any trigger could help with some condition to check jdbc??

Comment: "You cannot control the client" is a standard phrase in security. This is a universal and eternal truth. Whatever you are trying to do, it's wrong

Comment: I suspect that we didn't understand the question correctly. Can you explain in more detail what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using with combination of `ApplicationName` connection parameter and custom trigger. This is not secure, just prevents unintended changes.

You can see SQL Server example here https://thesqldude.com/2012/04/07/how-to-prevent-users-from-accessing-sql-server-from-any-application-or-any-login-expect-your-main-application-its-login/

Comment: This could be faked. I suspect that this is impossible to enforce this.

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned that in my answer, all methods are reliable to some extent, ip filter, separate user etc.